# Installing 10.04 server on HP xw9400 Workstation with RAID 5

Tags: 10.04, installation, server, raid

I have a workstation that was given to me that is a friggen powerhouse, so I figured I would set it up as my development and demo server.  This is my first experience installing Ubuntu onto a RAID array and so far it has not been a fun one.  I have been following the [Advanced Installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/advanced-installation.html) for installing Ubuntu 10.04 server, and it says that there will be an option on the Partition Disks screen to manually create the partitions, but the only options I have are:

- Configure iSCSI volumes
- Undo changes to partitions
- Finish partitioning and write changes to disk

Just before I got to that screen I got a message that said:

> One or more drives containing Serial ATA RAID configurations have been found.  Do you wish to activate these RAID devices?

It doesn't matter whether I answer yes or no to that, I still get the same Partition Disks screen.  When I try to select `Finish partitioning and write changes to disk` I just get the `No root file system` error.

Has anyone else experienced this, and how do I get past it?  Can I not run Ubuntu on this machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a fakeraid, not hardware raid.  See http://wiki.ubuntu.com/FakeRaidHowto for more information.  I suggest that you go into the bios utility and delete the raid array, then follow the instructions to setup an mdadm linux software raid.

This basically involves creating a raid partition on each disk, then creating the raid array built from those partitions, then using that array for your root filesystem.